# How can I reset Xcode 4 keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: xcode4

How can I reset Xcode 4 keyboard shortcuts to the default values? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mv ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings/Default.idekeybindings ~/
```

This will make a backup copy just in case. Then start XCode, view the Keybinding preferences, and restart XCode. This will create a blank default Default.idekeybindings file.

Edit: As per the comment response, first Quit XCode. Then if you want to reset a particular binding, you'll have to edit the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings/Default.idekeybindings` File and remove the `<key></key>` element that has the keycode that was overridden, and the `<string></string>` element that comes after it.

Comment: What if the default keybindings has already been modified without backup ?